# How to iterate through all fields of an object

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. Someone please show me how to store a map in local storage. Below is what I've tried.  After storing I don't seem to be able to iterate the map keys.
UDATE2: IT MIGHT BE THE serializeObject function.
          Why am I using this function?  Otherwise when I post in AJAX, I get:
          Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

UPDATE: LOOKS LIKE THE PROBLEM IS BEFORE IT EVER GOES INTO LOCAL STORAGE.

```
var reportId = getGUID();

var theReports = localStorage.getItem('reports');
if (theReports == null) {
    theReports = {};
}

theReports[reportId] = JSON.stringify($('#reportInfo').serializeObject());

// HERE ALSO I AM SEEING HUNDREDS OF FIELDS. I EXPECTED JUST reportID. I AM NOT SEEING THE KEY reportId. THIS IS BEFORE IT GOES INTO LOCAL STORAGE.

for (var prop in theReports)
{
   console.log(prop);
}

localStorage.setItem('reports', JSON.stringify(theReports));
var tReports = localStorage.getItem('reports');

// This prints out 1,2,3,...500 for every field in #reportInfo form 
// What I was expecting is reportId1, reportId2 etc. and definitely not the id of each field of the report itself!
for (var property in tReports) {
    if (tReports.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log(property);
    }
}
```

Here is the serializeObject function. Perhaps this is the problem.

```
$(function() {


  $.fn.serializeObject = function(){

  var self = this,
  json = {},
  push_counters = {},
  patterns = {
  "validate": /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?:\[(?:\d*|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\])*$/,
  "key":      /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|(?=\[\])/g,
  "push":     /^$/,
  "fixed":    /^\d+$/,
  "named":    /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
  };


  this.build = function(base, key, value){
  base[key] = value;
  return base;
  };

  this.push_counter = function(key){
  if(push_counters[key] === undefined){
  push_counters[key] = 0;
  }
  return push_counters[key]++;
  };

  $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(){

         // skip invalid keys
         if(!patterns.validate.test(this.name)){
         return;
         }

         var k,
         keys = this.name.match(patterns.key),
         merge = this.value,
         reverse_key = this.name;

         while((k = keys.pop()) !== undefined){

         // adjust reverse_key
         reverse_key = reverse_key.replace(new RegExp("\\[" + k + "\\]$"), '');

         // push
         if(k.match(patterns.push)){
         merge = self.build([], self.push_counter(reverse_key), merge);
         }

         // fixed
         else if(k.match(patterns.fixed)){
         merge = self.build([], k, merge);
         }

         // named
         else if(k.match(patterns.named)){
         merge = self.build({}, k, merge);
         }
         }

         json = $.extend(true, json, merge);
         });

  return json;
  };
```

Comment: Could you post the whole `tReports`?

Comment: Basically I am saving off a form of several report fields. tRepports should point to theReports which was stored in localStorage.

Comment: after setting theReports[reportId] = xyz,  i thought that iterating theReports would give me property= reportId.

Comment: you are still getting `theReports` out of the local storage. As Bart suggested. You have to use `JSON.parse()` to convert the string in an array. Otherwise `theReports` will also be a string and you are iterating over each letter. So change `var theReports = localStorage.getItem('reports');` to `var theReports = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reports'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tReports = localStorage.getItem('reports');
```

The variable `tReports` now holds the stringified version of the reports object.

---

The `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` only store a key/value pair as a string.

So if you wan't to store an object you need to serialize it to a string.

```
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

If you wan't to retrieve it from storage you need to deserialize it first before you can use it.

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FStorage

Comment: Please see my update. I am seeing hundreds of keys, names before storing in local storage.

Comment: I updated with serializeObject method. Perhaps this is causing the problem.

Comment: I am using this method because otherwise I get: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: A **circular structure** is probably a function or object inside your object to be serialized. Those need to be removed.

Comment: @MoreQuestionsThanAnswers You still need to parse the object retrieved from storage before you can use it. Otherwise you're operating on a string instead of an object.

Answer (score 4):

The for..in loop gives you only the keys and not the items itself. You get the items with `tReports[property]`

```
var obj = {
    "1": "one",
    "2": "two",
    "3": "three"
};

for (var key in obj) {
   console.log(key); //1, 2, 3
   console.log(obj[key]); //one, two, three
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing the key.

Comment: Well your line `console.log(property);` definitely prints the keys (property names) or indices (for arrays) of your object `tReports`. But i don't know what's inside of `tReports`. Based on what you wrote, it appeared that you're printing out indices of an array, when you actually want to print out the items of that array.

Comment: @MoreQuestionsThanAnswers usually when people say `key` in this context, they are referring to property names. When you have a line such as `obj[foo] = bar`, `obj` is a hashmap, where `foo` is the `key` and `bar` is the `value`.

Comment: Right, but the problem is that I am seeing hundreds of keys. I just save one report and after that I see literally hundreds of keys even though I only set a few reports.

Comment: Well, some other point of your code must be setting them. Try debugging it to see where the keys come from.

Comment: ok. I think it is the serializeObject method.  Should I be using something else to serialize?

Comment: If I don't use this method I get Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: I think that you should create a new question specifically for that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
console.log(property);
```

Do:

```
console.log(tReports[property]);
```

Since the `property` variable is the actual property name, not its value.

Comment: the problem is I am seeing hundreds of fields for property.  This is true before and after local storage.  Seems that I am seeing a property for everything on the right hand side of the tReports[property]

Comment: I used serializeObject method to send as post in $ajax call.